# C++: use void as template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, callback, template-meta-programming

I have this minimal class to represent an event which client can subscribe to.
The event can have an data type associated to it, so when it is triggered by a publisher, an argument of that type would be passed to the client's callback:

```cpp
template<typename Arg, typename Callback = function<void(const Arg&)>>
class Event
{
public:
    Event(Callback c) : mCallback(c){}
    
    void Trigger(const Arg& arg) {
        mCallback(arg);
    }

private:
    Callback mCallback;
};
```

Now I can create an `Event<int>` or any other concrete type, but it is really important to me to also allow "empty" event, which has no data associated with it: `Event<void>`

But sadly that doesn't work:

```cpp
static void FooVoid() {
    cout << "Look ma, no args!" << endl;
}

static void FooInt(int a) {
    cout << "int arg " << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
    /* Compiles */
    Event<int> eInt(&FooInt);
    eInt.Trigger(42);

    /* Does not compile :(
    Event<void> eVoid(&FooVoid);
    eVoid.Trigger();
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this desired API? How?

(P.S the solution should work on C++11)

Comment: Is `CallBack` actually customizable?

Comment: You need to specialize the class template for void.

Comment: IMO this should work with a variadic template.

Comment: @tkausl Is there a DRY way to do it other than complete copy-paste for void?

Comment: @Jarod42 it is not customizable but directly depends on Arg, which is a template parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way of solving this without explicitly specializing for `void` is to use a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) (added in C++11) for your template argument instead of a single type and using an empty parameter pack instead of `void`. A parameter pack can homogeneously hold any number of type, including 0 and 1. Then it can be used to generate the right types and member functions. You basically just have to add `...` correctly near every use of `Arg` ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/rdsxnsMeq)) :

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ... Arg>
class Event
{
public:
    using Callback = std::function<void(const Arg&...)>;

    Event(Callback c) : mCallback(c){}
    
    void Trigger(const Arg& ... arg) {
        mCallback(arg...);
    }

private:
    Callback mCallback;
};

static void FooVoid() {
    std::cout << "Look ma, no args!" << std::endl;
}

static void FooInt(int a) {
    std::cout << "int arg " << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    /* Compiles */
    Event<int> eInt(&FooInt);
    eInt.Trigger(42);

    Event<> eVoid(&FooVoid);
    eVoid.Trigger();
    
    return 0;
}
```

This has the added benefit that you can use callbacks with more than one argument. If this isn't desirable you can add a `static_assert` to prevent it :

```
template<typename ... Arg>
class Event
{
public:
    using Callback = std::function<void(const Arg&...)>;
    static_assert(sizeof...(Arg) <= 1, "Too many arguments");

    Event(Callback c) : mCallback(c){}
    
    void Trigger(const Arg& ... arg) {
        mCallback(arg...);
    }

private:
    Callback mCallback;
};
```

Notice that this solution requires `Event<>` instead of `Event<void>`. You can solve that by adding a short specialization for `Event<void>` that uses `Event<>` ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/vMx1WKb5v)) :

```
template<>
class Event<void> : public Event<>
{
    // Inherit constructors
    using Event<>::Event;
};
```

Comment: Possibly `static_assert(sizeof...(Args) < 2, "!");` to mimic OP limitation.